# Append a constant string to all the Slf4j logs in particular classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, slf4j

I have few classes that i use for my spring batch job execution like one below. I want to append a constant string SPRING_BATCH_JOB to the names of loggers of all these classes so that it will make my log filtering easier. I tried passing topic to  @Slf4j annotation (`@Slf4j(topic = "SPRING_BATCH_LOG")`
). It will just print this constant literal and will not print the class name. That is not exactly what i want to achieve.

For an instance, I want to print the log statement         `log.info("Creating a retry job execution")` as `{"@timestamp":"2023-03-21T05:34:24.345+00:00","message":"Creating a retry job execution","logger":"SPRING_BATCH_LOG : c.v.r.r.c. RetryOb","thread":"http-nio-8086-exec-2","level":"INFO"}`.

Is there any way to achieve this ???

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RetryOb {

  private final RetryJobService retryJobService;

  public void retry(retryRequest retryRequest) {
    log.info("Creating a retry Initiate job execution");
    retryService.startJob(retryRequest);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can use **MDC**, see [Baeldung's article](https://www.baeldung.com/mdc-in-log4j-2-logback).

Not all `slf4j`'s binder/loggers support this feature. As far as I know `logback` one who supports it => [Chapter 8: Mapped Diagnostic Context](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html)

If you want to suppress a class name tune a [custom layout](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html).

To get JSON output try to use [`logback`'s JSON appender](https://www.baeldung.com/java-log-json-output).